# sbt could not find implicit value for parameter valName

Tags: scala, implicit, chisel, rocket-chip

I'm using sbt to build some of the riscv boom from the source code, but the sbt complains that it "could not find implicit value for parameter valName: : freechips.rocketchip.diplomacy.ValName". The detailed error message are as below:

```
[error] F:\hiMCU\my_proj\src\main\scala\freechips\rocketchip\tile\BaseTile.scala:170:42: could not find implicit value for parameter valName: freechips.rocketchip.diplomacy.ValName
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[error]   protected val tlMasterXbar = LazyModule(new TLXbar)
```

The code where sbt complains is as below:

```
abstract class BaseTile private (val crossing: ClockCrossingType, q: Parameters)
    extends LazyModule()(q)
    with CrossesToOnlyOneClockDomain
    with HasNonDiplomaticTileParameters
{
    // Public constructor alters Parameters to supply some legacy compatibility keys
    def this(tileParams: TileParams, crossing: ClockCrossingType, lookup: LookupByHartIdImpl, p: Parameters) = {
        this(crossing, p.alterMap(Map(
            TileKey -> tileParams,
            TileVisibilityNodeKey -> TLEphemeralNode()(ValName("tile_master")),
            LookupByHartId -> lookup
    )))
}

def module: BaseTileModuleImp[BaseTile]
def masterNode: TLOutwardNode
def slaveNode: TLInwardNode
def intInwardNode: IntInwardNode    // Interrupts to the core from external devices
def intOutwardNode: IntOutwardNode  // Interrupts from tile-internal devices (e.g. BEU)
def haltNode: IntOutwardNode        // Unrecoverable error has occurred; suggest reset
def ceaseNode: IntOutwardNode       // Tile has ceased to retire instructions
def wfiNode: IntOutwardNode         // Tile is waiting for an interrupt

protected val tlOtherMastersNode = TLIdentityNode()
protected val tlSlaveXbar = LazyModule(new TLXbar)
protected val tlMasterXbar = LazyModule(new TLXbar)
protected val intXbar = LazyModule(new IntXbar)
....
}
```

The LazyModule object code is as below:

```
object LazyModule
{
    protected[diplomacy] var scope: Option[LazyModule] = None
    private var index = 0

    def apply[T <: LazyModule](bc: T)(implicit valName: ValName, sourceInfo: SourceInfo): T = {
        // Make sure the user put LazyModule around modules in the correct order
        // If this require fails, probably some grandchild was missing a LazyModule
        // ... or you applied LazyModule twice
        require (scope.isDefined, s"LazyModule() applied to ${bc.name} twice ${sourceLine(sourceInfo)}")
        require (scope.get eq bc, s"LazyModule() applied to ${bc.name} before ${scope.get.name} ${sourceLine(sourceInfo)}")
        scope = bc.parent
        bc.info = sourceInfo
        if (!bc.suggestedNameVar.isDefined) bc.suggestName(valName.name)
        bc
    }
}
```

I think the sbt should find some val of type freechips.rocketchip.diplomacy.ValName, but it didn't find such kind of val.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an object of type `ValName` in the scope where your `LazyModule`s are instantiated:

```scala
implicit val valName = ValName("MyXbars")
```

For more details on Scala's implicit please see https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/implicit-parameters.html.html

Comment: I have an object in another file ValName.scala,
object ValName{
  implicit def materialize(implicit x: ValNameImpl): ValName = ValName(x.name)
}
The ValName object and where the LazyModule are instantiated are in different files, but in the same package: package freechips.rocketchip.diplomacy. Will sbt use the object for the implicit parameter?

Comment: @qqyang10110 That other object would probably not be in scope, unless e.g. you import it. Best practice is to define the `implicit` objects as locally as possible. So I'd recommend you create a new instance.

Comment: It it's the companion object of `ValName`, implicits of this type _will_ be looked up there, but there may be no implicit `ValNameImpl`.

Answer (score 0):

You generally shouldn't need to manually create a `ValName`, the Scala compiler can materialize them automatically based on the name of the val you're assigning the `LazyModule` to. You didn't include your imports in your example, but can you try importing `ValName`?

```
import freechips.rocketchip.diplomacy.ValName
```

In most of rocket-chip code, this is imported via wildcard importing everything in the `diplomacy` package

```
import freechips.rocketchip.diplomacy._
```